# How can I assign values to an array in D3 using a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

In the following code I wish to assign values to the variable arr. Currently I am doing it manually by referring to each index of points array. Is there a way to to do it in a single step , by using a for loop or something similar.

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 2000)
        .attr("height", 2000);

var scren = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 4];
var maximum =d3.max(scren);

var points = d3.range(1, maximum).map(function(i) {
    return [i * 2000 / (maximum), 350];
});     

var arr = [
    {d: 'M ' + points[1][0] +' 350 A 10 10 0 1 0 '+ points[0][0]+' 350', stroke: 'green', 'strokewidth': 2, fill: 'none'},
    {d: 'M ' + points[2][0] +' 350 A 10 5 0 1 0 ' + points[1][0]+' 350', stroke: 'green', 'strokewidth': 2, fill: 'none'},
    // etc..
];

svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(arr)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', function(d) {return d.d;})
    .attr('stroke', function(d) {return d.stroke;})
    .attr('stroke-width', function(d) {return d.strokewidth;})
    .attr('fill', function(d) {return d.fill;});

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(points)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d[0];
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d[1];
    })
    .attr("r", 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a for loop if you need, and you can use the length of your array to set the limits of the loop. I'm not sure about what do you have inside `points` but you could do something like:

var arr = [];

```
for (i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) { 
    arr.push({d: 'M ' + points[i+1][0] +' 350 A 10 5 0 1 0 ' + points[i][0]+' 350', stroke: 'green', 'strokewidth': 2, fill: 'none'})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example `arr` you have, this should work:

```
var arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
    arr.push({d: 'M ' + points[scren[i]][0] +' 350 A 10 10 0 1 0 '+ points[i][0]+' 350',
        stroke: 'green', 'strokewidth': 2, fill: 'none'});
}
```

I'm not quite sure where you got the 4th value in `' 350 A 10 10 0 1 0 '` from, though.
I also assumed that in the first `points[]`, you wanted the contents of `scren`, since those seemed to match.

Any way, this should give you an idea on how to fill the array.